# Use Twitter Bootstrap button group as radio select with knockout bindings

Tags: mvvm, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal

This is working:

**view.html**

```
<div><input type="radio" name="radioPriority" data-bind="checked: priority" value="want" style="margin-top: -3px; margin-right: 3px;" />I want to</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="radioPriority" data-bind="checked: priority" value="need"  style="margin-top: -3px; margin-right: 3px;"/>I need to</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
function feedbackViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.priority = ko.observable("want");
    //lots of other stuff
}
```

As expected, when you select the second radio the priority observable's value changes to "need".  However, I'd like to use a Twitter Bootstrap button group as a radio.  Here is the HTML I have, but it does not change the observable as expected:

```
<span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button data-bind="checked: priority" type="button" class="btn" value="want">I want to</button>
    <button data-bind="checked: priority" type="button" class="btn" value="need">I need to</button>
</span>
```

**update** I have a jsfiddle going here:  http://jsfiddle.net/a8wa8/6/  "priority1" is the standard radio selects and "priority2" is the bootstrap buttons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `Checked` binding with button which is not allowed, instead you can use click binding. check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8wa8/7/

**Updated:**

Yes you can achieve this by using ko `css binding`. Check this updated fiddle:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8wa8/8/)

Comment: This works well except that when I change the model it doesn't update the view.  ie, setting priority2('want') pragmatically does not select the appropriate button.  Is this easily doable?

Comment: @ScottBeeson please check my updated answer and let me know is this what you want ?

Comment: @gaurav Is it possible to move the `data-bind` attribute's content to a js file? If possible, how would it look?

Comment: @Skytiger Why you want to move data-bind attribute to js file ? The main purpose of data-bind is to bind your data model with your view model. If you are trying to use data-bind with dynamic elements than you can applyBindings to that newly created element like `ko.applyBindings(yourmodel, document.getElementById('newElementId'));`

Comment: Good stuff! I've revised the fiddle to demonstrate how programmatic changes to the model are reflected back to the button group: http://jsfiddle.net/yvopLvsu/1/ (I've also modified the JS code to use `===` and added a couple of missing semicolons)

Answer (score 6):

The [checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) only works with "checkable" controls like checkbox (`<input type='checkbox'>`) or a radio button (`<input type='radio'>`).

But you have `button` in your second example where bootstrap just emulates the look of the radio button group so the `checked` binding doesn't work.

However you can use the [`click` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) where you pass the value to your observable:

```
<span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
     <button data-bind="click: function() { priority2('want') }" 
             type="button" class="btn" value="want">I want to</button>
     <button data-bind="click: function() { priority2('need') }" 
             type="button" class="btn" value="need">I need to</button>    
</span>
```

And you can hide this behind a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueClick = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                  viewModel, bindingContext) {     
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var newValueAccessor = function() {
            return function() {
                value(element.value); 
            };
        };
        ko.bindingHandlers.click.init(element, newValueAccessor, 
            allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
<span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
     <button data-bind="valueClick: priority2" 
             type="button" class="btn" value="want">I want to</button>
     <button data-bind="valueClick: priority2" 
             type="button" class="btn" value="need">I need to</button>    
</span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wy4P/)

Comment: This also works, though it's much more complex than gaurav's answer, but it has the same issue.  It's not a two way binding.  If I set priority('want') and priority2('want') you'll see that the radio is automatically selected but the bootstrap button is not.

Comment: If you also want to have the two way binding then you need to combine the `click` with the `css` binding. My `valueClick` custom bindinghandler can be extended to handle this case also. At first it may seem complicated but it is much more maintainable solution. Because in your accepted answer you have to repeat "want" and "need" 3 times and "priority2" 2 times on the buttons. At the other hand with a custom binding you need to write everything once.

Comment: @nemesv Duuuuude your solutions is perfect for what I need. Thanks, I'll need to extend `valueClick`'s functionality to handle the two way binding, like you said, but so far it's perfect.

Comment: @nemesv Your example helped me in two ways; it solved the same button group problem and showed me I didn't need a 'toggle' function on the view model. Because observables are functions you can simply pass a new value in the binding click event. Cheers.