# How can I get Bootstrap toggle buttons to update Knockout viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I've got a bootstrap toggle button with a nested checkbox:

```html
<div class="btn-group"  data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn btn-info">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Click me</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it works fine (see [this jsffidle - Bootstrap Toggle Button](http://jsfiddle.net/johnmacintyre/xabtzLuu/)).

However, when I add Knockout into the mix:

```html
<div class="btn-group"  data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="btn btn-info">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showMessage" />
        <span>Click me</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

my viewmodel property isn't getting updated. However, if I just have a checkbox alone ...

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="sanityCheckbox" data-bind="checked: sanityCheckboxValue"/>
```

... everything's fine (see [this jsfiddle - Why doesn't Knockout work with Bootstrap toggle buttons?](http://jsfiddle.net/johnmacintyre/uvfatyat/)).

I suspect the `change` event isn't getting triggered when bootstrap sets the checkbox.  Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: the checkbox doesn't appear to be changing if you have a look in chrome inspector

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077475/knockout-bootstrap-3-radio-buttons) may help

Comment: Thanks @anpsmn, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I tested the checkbox adaptation at http://jsfiddle.net/MEA33/1/ and everything appears to work as expected.  I've put in a vote to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnMacIntyre no answers or votes... you could just delete it yourself?

Comment: @Tanner I don't think it should be deleted, because I obviously couldn't find the other question and leaving this here acts as a beacon to others looking for the same thing.  IMHO, the question is written well enough that it clearly demonstrates the problem as well, which hopefully might also add value.  If we just close it, that value is saved, but the answers are still streamlined to a single Q/A point.  ... that's my reasoning for what it's worth.

Comment: @JohnMacIntyre fair enough, sounds reasonable I'll add a vote for you.