# binding a Knockout observable property to a bootstrap radio button value fails

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, data-binding, radio-button

Is it possible to bind a Knockout observable property to a radio button value?

I have 3 bootstrap radio buttons

```
<div class="tgl-btns-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn tgl-btn active">
        <input type="radio" name="flavors" value="cherry" autocomplete="off" data-bind="checked: spamFlavors" />Cherry</label>
    <label class="btn tgl-btn">
        <input type="radio" name="flavors" value="almond" autocomplete="off" data-bind="checked: spamFlavors" />Almond</label>
    <label class="btn tgl-btn">
        <input type="radio" name="flavors" value="msg" autocomplete="off" data-bind="checked: spamFlavors" />Monosodium Glutamate</label>
</div>
Radio value: <span data-bind='text: check'></span>
```

and my knockout model is as follows

```
var Model = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.spamFlavors = ko.observable('cherry');
    self.check = self.spamFlavors();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new Model());
});
```

the result is that the radio value is always cherry despite of a different radio button are clicked.

Here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/pagowdho/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the value of `check` to `spamFlavors()`,  you basically set it to the initial value, which is `'cherry'`. So it is not an observable any more and will not update on change.
You should bind the `span` to `spamFlavors`, then it (theoretically) updates on change.

```
Radio value: <span data-bind='text: spamFlavors'></span>
```

The problem is that Bootstrap handles the `click event` and prevents it from bubbling, so knockout can't update the binding.
You have multiple ways to circumvent that:

**1)**
Remove `data-toggle="buttons"`. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pagowdho/6/)

**2)**
Use a custom knockout binding, like the one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080917/3107430) answer.

**3)**
Update the value yourself using an event handler. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pagowdho/8/)

```
event: { change: function(d, e) { spamFlavors(e.target.value); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/faulknercs/Knockstrap/blob/master/src/bindings/radioBinding.js) knockout binding to work with bootstrap.js radio buttons group controls. You will have to include the binding and then modify your html as

```
<div class="tgl-btns-group" data-toggle="buttons" data-bind="radio: spamFlavors">
    <label class="btn tgl-btn active">
        <input type="radio" name="flavors" value="cherry" autocomplete="off"  />Cherry</label>
    <label class="btn tgl-btn">
        <input type="radio" name="flavors" value="almond" autocomplete="off"  />Almond</label>
    <label class="btn tgl-btn">
        <input type="radio" name="flavors" value="msg" autocomplete="off" />Monosodium Glutamate</label>
</div>
Radio value: <span data-bind='text: spamFlavors'></span>
```

JsFiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/pagowdho/7/