# bootstrap js radio buttons not working but normal onces are

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, radio-button

I have normal radio buttons that I am using to change looks around the page. And it works perfectly fine. I am using knockout js binding to give it functionality.
Here is the HTML and the JS part all together.

```
<h4 class="radio-inline" data-bind="visible: loggedIn() == 'true'"><input type="radio" value="Borrow" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue">Money1</h4>
<h4 class="radio-inline" data-bind="visible: loggedIn() == 'true'"><input type="radio" value="Invest" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue">Money2</h4>
```

Here is the JS file for the checkedbinding.

```
self.radioSelectedOptionValue = ko.observable(radioSelectedOptionValue);
```

All the codes Above work perfectly like it should but now I wanted to make the normal looking radio buttons into proper buttons by using bootstrap js buttons but now the radio buttons do not function anymore.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="visible: loggedIn() == 'true'">
              <input type="radio" value="Borrow" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" >Money1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="visible: loggedIn() == 'true'">
              <input type="radio" value="Invest" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" > Money2
            </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the answers here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077475/knockout-bootstrap-3-radio-buttons

Comment: @user3297291 I did but if the old functionality works the new one should too, only thing dats changing is the style of the button

Comment: From the first answer in that question: > "bootstrap subscribes on the click event to do the toggling but calls e.preventDefault() so KO won't be notified about the click" http://stackoverflow.com/a/20080917/3297291

Comment: @user3297291 I already have a subscriber in place for that 
`self.radioSelectedOptionValue = ko.observable(radioSelectedOptionValue);
        self.radioSelectedOptionValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            if (newValue === 'Borrow') {
               // do something
                
            }
           
        });`

Comment: 1. The knockout `checked` binding *depends on default behavior*. 2. Bootstrap *blocks default behavior*. 3. Knockout is never able to detect the change and change your observable from true to false (https://jsfiddle.net/6fop1sb9/)

Comment: @user3297291 any easy way to solve it? I am not even sure how to write a binding handler